# Why does page 323 from Automate The boring Stuff generate an int of 21?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm going back through the book "[Automate the boring stuff](https://coderanch.com/t/651408/languages/Automate-Boring-Stuff-book)" (which has been a great book btw)as I need to brush up on CSV parsing for a project and I'm trying to understand why each output is generated. Why does this code from page 323 create an output of '21', when it's four words, 16 characters, and three commas. Not to mention that I'm entering strings and it outputs numbers.

```
#%%
import csv
outputFile = open('output.csv', 'w', newline='')
outputWriter = csv.writer(outputFile)
outputWriter.writerow(['spam', 'eggs', 'bacon', 'ham'])
```

First I thought ok it's the number of characters, but that adds up to 16. Then I thought ok each word maybe has a space plus one at the beginning and end of the CSV file? Which does technically maybe explain but nothing explicit, it's more "oh it's obvious because " but it's not explicitly stated. I'm not seeing a reference to the addition of or how that number is created.

There seems like a plausible explanation but I don't understand why it's 21.

[image: why is the output '21'?]

I've tried breakpoint or pdb but I'm still learning how to use those, to get the following breakdown which I don't see containing anything that answers it. No counting or summation that I can see.

[image]

Comment: From https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow . `"Return the return value of the call to the write method of the underlying file object."` Your underlying file object is `outputFile`. Defined here https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=file%20write#io.TextIOBase.write as returning the number of characters written. Which is `21` with the delimiters and newline. Open it up in a text editor and see for yourself.

Comment: Also in future when referencing a book, please include the  edition number you are using.  I find your problem on page 374 of the 2nd edition.

Comment: These are both good comments and I will remember to include the edition number. Since I'm still new to SO proper procedure and seeing how @Axe319 solved the problem how do I mark that answer as accepted?

Comment: @CoffeeBaconAddict You can't accept comments as answers but you can accept the answer I posted if you feel that it answered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) state that `csv.csvwriter.csvwriterow` returns `"the return value of the call to the write method of the underlying file object."`.

In your example

```
outputFile = open('output.csv', 'w', newline='')
```

is your underlying file object which you then hand to `csv.writer()`.

If we look a bit deeper we can find the `type` of `outputFile` with `print(type(outputFile))`.

```
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
```

While the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=file%20write#io.TextIOWrapper) don't explicitly define the `write` method for `TextIOWrapper`, it does state that it inherits from `TextIOBase`, which [defines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=file%20write#io.TextIOBase) it's `write()` method as `"Write the string s to the stream and return the number of characters written."`.

If we look at the text file written:

```
spam,eggs,bacon,ham
```

We see that it indeed has 21 characters.